# Raspberry Pi to monitor all HTTP requests to/from Router

Tags: networking, monitoring

I would like to be able to view all the HTTP requests that my router receives (in the kind of way Fiddler monitors on a PC). I would like to monitor all incoming and outgoing traffic with the HTTP protocol. Is there any way I can do this without changing settings on the devices accessing the router? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe you can flash your router to use a custom firmware (e.g. OpenWRT) with packets like tshark or tcpdump. Depends on your router

Comment: Is this on the LAN side or the WAN side ? It'd be pretty much impossible on the WAN side.

Comment: I was looking for something that would not actually involve changing much on my router, if anything at all. I would be connecting it to the router by an ethernet cable if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

have you tried wireshark? Thuis should be a start. Not as fancy as fiddler, though.

Comment: your answer is quite short, could you please elaborate about wireshark, fiddler, maybe provide some links or references or briefly outline the usage pattern?